# 02 Honda Accord EX~ Rear brakes

Tags: brakes

My brakes have been fine... about a month ago i could hear a faint *click click click* noise in sync with the rotation of the wheel while braking. it has now evolved into both rear wheels, and i can hear it at lower speeds while driving. While braking it is louder. Also does the noise while the e-brake is applied, but if i stop and pull me e-brake a few times the noise gets softer, but still gets louder. my question is what is the issue? the problem started randomly and is also noteworthy that i was almost in an accident and hit the brakes very hard about 2 weeks ago. clicking noise didn’t get worse that day but i noticed it got worse the following days. any help appreciated!

Comment: When were the brakes last serviced? Are the brake discs still in good shape when you do a visual inspection and do the brake pads still have friction material on them?